# Ubuntu - No touchpad tab in my Mouse preferences

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad

I have a laptop running Ubuntu Jaunty. This laptop has a touchpad. I want to turn off tap-to-click. [The ubuntu documentation for touchpads](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad), refers to a Touchpad tab on my System -> Prefereces -> Mouse settings, but there is none. Is there something I need to install?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to install the **gsynaptics** package as the [Ubuntu community document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) states:

> **Ubuntu**
>
> - Enable SHMConfig.
> - For a preference tool which
>     integrates into the GNOME Desktop
>     environment, install the **gsynaptics**
>     package from the universe repository.
>     For help with installing packages see
>     InstallingSoftware.
>
> After installation, gsynaptics can be
>   found under System > Preferences >
>   Touchpad.